# WebAPI I can convert CLR properties to lowercase first letter, but on POST and PUT case conversion not happening

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Using the below formatter, I convert properties in my C# classes that are naturally beginning with uppercase to lowercase.  However, when I turn around and post those back to POST and PUT, they are coming back up in lowercase first letter and of course that does not map back to the C# class.

What is best way to handle data going back to POST and PUT without having to parse the javascript and do the conversions by hand?

```
config.Formatters[index] =
            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
                {
                    SerializerSettings =
                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                            {
                                ContractResolver =
                                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
                                        (),
                                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
                                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                            }
                };
```

Comment: I've never had casing problem with Json -> Class Mapping. Can you  explain the context (controller) with a sample Json and the class ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` you can simply modify the existing JSON formatter as follows:

```
httpConfiguration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
```

Maybe that will work...

Comment: Turns out the json formatter must be case insensative because it just worked after I played with it some more.